# include_blank false doesn't work for collection_select in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm trying to use collection_select for a form in Rails3 with a default value, but without a blank option. I'm using the following line, but the blank value keeps showing up.

```
f.collection_select(:user_id, @users, :id, :name, {:selected => current_user.id, :include_blank => false})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stick with:

```
f.collection_select(:user_id, @users, :id, :name)
```

and set the default in your controller:

```
def new
  @my_obj = MyObject.new(:user_id=>defaulted_user_id)
end
```

If that doesn't work, ensure the user you are defaulting is responding to user.name correctly or even if it has a name value set.  Since you might actually be setting the id but the user doesn't have a "name" and would therefore show as a blank.